# How does `[]` conform to NSRegularExpressionOptions?

Tags: swift

Code:

```
    let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)[Ee]([+-]?\\d+)", options: [])
```

Now `options` should be of the type `NSRegularExpressionOptions`, how does `[]` conform to that?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066170/how-to-create-ns-options-style-bitmask-enumerations-in-swift

Comment: The reason is that OptionSetType conforms to ArrayLiteralConvertible, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169597/swift-2-0-nil-or-0-enum-arguments or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863236/in-swift-what-does-this-specific-syntax-mean.